# how is jQuery able to call an object $

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

1. If `$` is an object then how is jQuery able to call it with parenthesis `()`, like `$('#MYdIV')`. That is my first and most important question.
2. I am trying to learn design patterns, and underlaying mechanisms of creating an object. So I want to make library that when user type `myLibrary({option1:true});` he would be able to instantiate an object without using keyword new.Just like jquery and this: https://github.com/bendc/animateplus/blob/master/animate.js
   In this example he is not using keyword `new` nor `this`. He is just creating IIFE animate which returns another function with the same name. I don't know how is he able to do that. Is animate bound to global object?

Comment: I got `>typeof $ <-
"function"`

Comment: Functions are objects in Javascript. That is how. Read an introductory article about Javascript.

Comment: so $ is a constructor function?

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L18

Comment: Any function *can* be called as a constructor function. Whether it is supposed to is a different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jQuery` or `$` is just a function. Consider the following example which produces an object with the similar behavior.
Of course, jQuery has the much more complex and smart structure, this is just an example:

```js
var not$ = function(o) {
  var result = document.querySelectorAll(o);
  
  result.customInnerText = function(text) {
      if (text === undefined) {
        return document.querySelector(o).innerText;
      } else {
        document.querySelector(o).innerText = text;
      }     
  };
  result.customClickHandler = function(callback) {
      document.querySelector(o).addEventListener('click', callback);
  };

  return result;
};
not$.customConsoleLog = function(text) {
    console.log(text);
};

not$("a").customClickHandler(function() {
  var exampleText = not$("#title").customInnerText();
  not$("#text").customInnerText(exampleText + "It works!");

  not$.customConsoleLog(not$("p").length);
  not$.customConsoleLog(not$("p")[0]);
});
```

```html
 
<a href="#">Click me!</a>

<p id="title">Example:</p>
<p id="text">Check!</p>
```

Comment: Nice! I was confused bc everybody use new keyword when creating library.

Comment: what if I want to return just `not$('a')` and get a list of `a` elements. How to do that in your code?

Comment: @SaleSale I guess, you want to use `querySelectorAll` :) Just google it.

Comment: but your code is returning an object, and that object doesn't have initialising method.

Comment: I don't want `not$('a').query()`, just a `not$('a')`

Comment: @SaleSale Oh, now I see. jQuery returns a custom array-like structure. Just for this example: you can create a returning object array, and add some functions to it. Check my update.

Comment: In your code you are assigning Node List to a variable result and adding methods to it. Is that the right  way to think about it ?

Comment: @SaleSale As I guess, that's why jQuery have implemented their own object and structure - to avoid such things. However, it doesn't sound wrong for me.

Comment: Node List is array-like Object so you could attach methods to that object, i guess ...tnx

Comment: I am not completely clear when you call `not$('a').customInnerText()` does that returns `document.querySelector(o).innerText;` or result from main function. In another words does that return result variable from the outher function or just its return statement?

Comment: `not$("selector")` returns an array-like object with custom functions, but `not$("selector").customInnerText()` returns a simple string which is the result of executing this function (`return`). If you provide a string to this function, then it changes the text content and returns nothing.

Comment: is outher return statement anyway affected when  I execute `not$("selector").customInnerText()`? Is that return statement(of outher function) executed if I call the function mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

(1) `$` is **not** an object, but a function.

```
console.log(typeof $);
// function
```

What might be confusing here - and this is *just a guess* - is that you can access properties on the `$` variable, e.g. `$.extend` or `$.fn` (used when writing your own jQuery plugins). This is normal, as functions can have properties themselves. The ECMAScript specifications allow that.

(2) Constructor functions can be used to create new objects, but **are not required**. You can just used object literals, and that works just as well. As pointed out by @Jeff in the other answer, a function invoked with `new` makes it a constructor function. Otherwise, there is no difference in the syntax. It is up to you to pick whether you wish to use.

Comment: Functions are objects.

Comment: @FelixKling point taken, just a case of me pointing out that a square is not a rectangle (even though it technically is)

Comment: Why then everybody use `new` keyword when writing library or code?

Comment: @SaleSale There's no need to follow blindly - I personally avoid using constructor functions, and use object literals in their place, with functions that perform operations on those objects, and I have found code written in this manner much easier to reason about. To each his own. As to why many use constructor functions, my best guess is that it is familiar if previously they have been programming in a pure OO language, and thus gravitate toward it.

Answer (score 1):

First a few terms:

- a primitive is [one of the following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive): string, number, boolean, null, undefined, symbol
- An object is essentially any kind of thing that's not a primitve in Javascript. If it's a thing you want to use or manipulate, it's an object.
- A function is a particular type of object that can be used to run javascript. This can be called by using the syntax `function()`
- A constructor is *just a function*. It's a function which is intended to be called with the `new` keyword, as in `new Thing()`. Note the capital letter - that's convention.

So we can see that JQuery uses a function, not a constructor function. Specifically, if you look into the source code we'll find something like `$ = function() {...}`

And that's basically it - they define a global variable called `$` and define it to be a function that can be used. Of course, since functions are objects, you can also do things like `$.randomNumber = 4` without problems, and it won't affect JQuery in the slightest.

So if you're wanting to do something similar, you'll want to define your own global variable and set it as a function - just be aware of what's already taken - i.e. don't use `$` or `_` or whatever.

Comment: Primitive values are not objects though.

Comment: @FelixKling haha, I was just about to comment on that. I'll edit it.

Comment: So, jQuery or $ is not a constructor function? Just an ordinary function atached to global object.

Comment: @SaleSale every function can be used as a constructor if you chuck the keyword `new` in front of it. Having said that, I wouldn't assume that anything useful would come out if you tried `var myJQuery = new $()`. So basically you're correct, but I think you're confusing constructors in JS with constructors in languages where they're *actually useful*.

Comment: Yes I know what is a constructor function in JS. It is just ordinary function. The key is keyword new: 1) it creates an object inside and makes JS engine to assign `this` to that object. 2) then attaches prototype to that object to be a prototype of constructor function.
So, I dont know following: Does new creates a link `__proto__` to a constructor function prototype or a property prototype on a object?

Comment: @SaleSale I'm not completely clear on what you're asking, but it sounds sufficiently far removed from your original question and my answer as to deserve a question of it's own, if you can't find one that already answers your question.